# Getting size of the text in a UITextView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uitextview

I'm trying to use a UIScrollView as a UITextView, except it will have a logo at the top (thus I can not use UITextView directly).

In other words; I will have a UIScrollView with a UIImage and a UITextView in it. The content for the textView is localized and liable to change, so I can not hardcode the height of it. Is there any way to get the "this is how big this field should be to fit all the text"-value so I can properly calculate the neede height of the UIScrollView?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would check out the UIStringDrawing Category for NSStrings which has the following method:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
```

Make the size property a struct with the width you want and use a large height value:

```
CGSizeMake(width, 999.0f)
```

Comment: You can use the constant FLT_MAX instead of the 999.0f

Comment: This works ok for UILabel. But, UITextView has internal margins that should be also observed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the methods defined in `NSString (UIStringDrawing)`:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font forWidth:(CGFloat)width lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
```

This will return the size (width and height) of the text. You may want to add a few pixel for a margin.

Comment: This looks just right. Except it only ever returns "21" as a height :/  I assume this is the height of one row in my case. I'm using lineBreakMode UILineBreakModeWordWrap. The text has some formating in it (newlines). Could that be the problem?

Thanks!